How to switch windows on only a single space on the active desktop using hammerspoon?
While switching windows with keyboard on MacOS, the default CMD+TAB command shows all the active windows. I use hammerspoon to switch only between windows on a single desktop.
This is the script I use for achieving that.
local wf = hs.window.filter
filter = wf.new():setCurrentSpace(true):setDefaultFilter{}
switcher_space = hs.window.switcher.new(filter)
hs.window.switcher.ui.showThumbnails = false
hs.window.switcher.ui.showSelectedThumbnail = false
hs.hotkey.bind('alt', 'tab', 'Next window', function()
    switcher_space:next()
    hs.alert.closeAll()
end)
hs.hotkey.bind('alt-shift', 'tab', 'Prev window', function()
    switcher_space:previous()
    hs.alert.closeAll()
end)

Similar to what we have in the documentation.
This is working fine for a single monitor. But when I connect one more monitor the switcher_space has windows on the active desktop with the windows on desktop on the other monitor. I would like to see only the windows from the active monitor (currently focused).
While reading the documentation I found that I have to use setScreens method on window filter. But using it like this
screen_id = hs.screen.primaryScreen():id()
filter = wf.new():setScreens(screen_id):setCurrentSpace(true):setDefaultFilter{}

throws
invalid key in filter table: _allowedScreens

